# SQL Server SMO - Backuping - How to determine failure / success?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, backup, smo

If you execute backup using SMO, after successful completion, I test the SqlError for null, considering that the backup completed without errors:

[image]

But, as you can see, it actually return an error of class 0 number 3014 meaning success.

So the question is:

> **Q: How can I find out if backup completed successfully or not, and how should I handle these messages and statuses cleanly?**

I'm afraid that there are multiple of "gotchas" here that I don't want to bite me in the ass later when this code goes production :)

Answer (score 3):

I agree there are multiple "gotchas" and I personally think Microsoft SMO events are poorly implemented as the ServerMessageEventArgs contains a Property Error which not always provides information about an error but messages about successful operations!!

As an example:
The "error" with code 4035 is an information message. Not an error.
The "error" with code 3014 is an information message that happens when completed successfully. Not an error

Also notice that the Information event does not always happen when an error has occurred. It actually happens whenever SQL Server sends a message that could be information about the operation that has finished successfully

I am also concerned about not handling the errors/success properly, but **checking sqlError as Null is a bad idea** since it will not be ever null and it will always contain some message about successful operation or an error. And **assuming that Information event occurs when there is an error is also a bad idea**.

I suggest to handle the errors through the SqlError.Number and depending on the SMO event it has been triggered.

I have made the following code to create a database backup. It is in VB.NET but in C# would be similar. It receives necessary parameters including a delegate where to invoke events (to be handled at GUI), a progress to report the percentage and error handling depending on event triggered and the SqlError.Number as mentioned

```
Public Sub BackupDatabase(databaseName As String, backupFileFullPath As String, optionsBackup As OptionsBackupDatabase, operationProgress As IProgress(Of Integer),
                          operationResult As Action(Of OperationResult)) Implements IDatabaseManager.BackupDatabase
    Dim sqlBackup As New Smo.Backup()
    sqlBackup.Action = Smo.BackupActionType.Database
    sqlBackup.BackupSetName = databaseName & " Backup"
    sqlBackup.BackupSetDescription = "Full Backup of " & databaseName
    sqlBackup.Database = databaseName
    Dim bkDevice As New Smo.BackupDeviceItem(backupFileFullPath, Smo.DeviceType.File)
    sqlBackup.Devices.Add(bkDevice)
    sqlBackup.Initialize = optionsBackup.Overwrite
    sqlBackup.Initialize = True
    sqlBackup.PercentCompleteNotification = 5

    AddHandler sqlBackup.PercentComplete, Sub(sender As Object, e As PercentCompleteEventArgs)
                                              operationProgress.Report(e.Percent)
                                          End Sub
    AddHandler sqlBackup.Complete, Sub(sender As Object, e As ServerMessageEventArgs)
                                       Dim sqlMessage As SqlClient.SqlError = e.Error
                                       Dim opResult As New OperationResult()
                                       Select Case sqlMessage.Number
                                           Case 3014
                                               opResult.operationResultType = OperationResultType.SmoSuccess
                                               opResult.message = "Backup successfully created at " & backupFileFullPath & ". " & sqlMessage.Number & ": " & sqlMessage.Message
                                           Case Else
                                               opResult.operationResultType = OperationResultType.SmoError
                                               opResult.message = "ERROR CODE " & sqlMessage.Number & ": " & sqlMessage.Message
                                       End Select
                                       operationResult.Invoke(opResult)
                                   End Sub

    AddHandler sqlBackup.NextMedia, Sub(sender As Object, e As ServerMessageEventArgs)
                                        Dim sqlMessage As SqlClient.SqlError = e.Error
                                        Dim opResult As New OperationResult()
                                        opResult.operationResultType = OperationResultType.SmoError
                                        opResult.message = "ERROR CODE:  " & sqlMessage.Number & ": " & sqlMessage.Message
                                        operationResult.Invoke(opResult)
                                    End Sub

    AddHandler sqlBackup.Information, Sub(sender As Object, e As ServerMessageEventArgs)
                                          Dim sqlMessage As SqlClient.SqlError = e.Error
                                          Dim opResult As New OperationResult()
                                          Select Case sqlMessage.Number
                                              Case 4035
                                                  opResult.operationResultType = OperationResultType.SmoInformation
                                                  opResult.message = sqlMessage.Number & ": " & sqlMessage.Message
                                              Case Else
                                                  opResult.operationResultType = OperationResultType.SmoError
                                                  opResult.message = "ERROR CODE " & sqlMessage.Number & ": " & sqlMessage.Message
                                          End Select
                                          operationResult.Invoke(opResult)
                                      End Sub
    Try
        sqlBackup.SqlBackupAsync(smoServer)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New BackupManagerException("Error backing up database " & databaseName, ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I could be wrong, but I believe that the [`Complete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.backuprestorebase.complete.aspx) event firing is the main indicator that the backup was successful - errors would be reported through the [`Information`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.backuprestorebase.information.aspx) event.

Since the class of the error is `0` (or any value below 10), it indicates that it's an informational message, not an actual error (`Error` is somewhat misnamed). And 3014 *is* defined as the message that's sent when the backup is successful.

I'm not sure what other "gotchas" you're concerned with, since you haven't documented them.