# ServerConnection | Backup Restore with Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoEnum Error - FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, smo, database-backups

I have written this code using references after googling a bit, however while executing `BackupDatabase(myfilename.bak)` it gives me error at line no. `11` and says:

**FileNotFoundException was unhandled**

`Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoEnum, Version=9.0.242.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

I have checked that the `SMO` file exists in my drive and in `bin` also. I am unable to understand the issue. Kindly help.

```
public readonly string ConnectionString = MyApp.Properties.Settings.Default.DbConnectionString;
public void BackupDatabase(string backUpFile)
    {
        ServerConnection con = new ServerConnection(ConnectionString);
        Server server = new Server(con);
        Backup source = new Backup();
        source.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
        source.Database = "TestDB";
        BackupDeviceItem destination = new BackupDeviceItem(backUpFile, DeviceType.File);
        source.Devices.Add(destination);
        source.SqlBackup(server);
        con.Disconnect();
    }
```

Also, i tried to do:

```
if(con.Isopen)
{
    //Then all of my code goes in here
}
```

But this condition never satisfies and the inside code never gets executed.

I also observed that like we use to do `con.open()` for `Database Connection`, we don't have such option with `ServerConnection`.

**EDIT-1:**

While debugging I found this with `con`

[image]

**EDIT-2:**

I have another query to this question: Does the connectionString of DB is same of the connection string of ServerConnection???

I am actually talking in regard to this line:-

`public readonly string ConnectionString = MyApp.Properties.Settings.Default.DbConnectionString;`

Because above `ConnectionString` contains `{server='Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyDb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True';Trusted_Connection=true;multipleactiveresultsets=false}`

Comment: have you added a reference to the dll in your project?

Answer (score 0):

To create a Smo connection you just need a ServerConnection, and to create a ServerConnection you just need the name of the SQL Server.
Example

```
ServerConnection serverConnection = new ServerConnection("mySQLServer")
Smo.Server smoServer = new Smo.Server(serverConnection)
```

As I can see you are using SQLExpress. Then your SQL Server instance will be called ".\SQLEXPRESS" by default, so you would have to do something like:

```
ServerConnection serverConnection = new ServerConnection(".\\SQLEXPRESS")
Smo.Server smoServer = new Smo.Server(serverConnection)
```

Notice the '\' to prevent escaping inside a string.

Have a look at my working example here in case it helps:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23096791/2948212